# Function composition in Haskell to calculate Power

Tags: haskell, function-composition

i am trying to write a power function in haskell that calculates f to the power of n, where f is a function itself, using function composition.

This is what I have so far:

```
let pow 0 f = (\x -> x)
    pow n f = f . (pow (n-1) f) 
in 2 ((\x -> x+1) 2)
```

I am expecting it to pass the function *f(x)=x+1* to power function and return the square of the function. I try passing in the value 2 to the *f(x)* function, so i thought it would return 4

When I run it on haskell.org I get:

```
:: (Num a, Num (a -> t)) => t
```

Answer (score 2):

Your line is invalid: `2 ((\x->x+1) 2)` is malformed (as it is equivalent to `2 3`).

```
let pow 0 f = (\x->x); pow n f = f.(pow (n-1) f) in (pow 2 (\x -> x + 1)) 2
```

does produce `4`.

Comment: hey, 
shouldnt the answer actually be 9? since its f^n and f = 2+1?

Comment: @Johnylikes3thirty: `f` is not `2 + 1`. `f` is the incrementing function, not a number; `f^2` is "apply `f` twice". Incrementing `2` twice yields `4`.